# Is there any specific function to find unique TP numbers comparing two sheets?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets, both of them containing tp numbers, I wanna write a function in which it searches both sheets and finds only unique tp numbers from first sheet that does not exist in the second sheet.

[image: my function, I brought two different tp numbers to one sheet to compare]

I tried it  by filtering A-z both sheets and if function if they are even write yes and if not write no.
But this is really dubious and long. I would like to know if there is any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=FILTER(G1:G3,ISERROR(XMATCH(G1:G3,J1:J4)))`

[image]

In your case it's `=FILTER(G1:G26,ISERROR(XMATCH(G1:G26,J1:J30)))`

Comment: thank you for your comment, it helped me a lot. one more thing. what if each tp has same code but different currency ,  for exp tp1 40usd, tp1 25 usd, i would like to do same thing with this  , how i can then find only uniques?

Comment: `=FILTER(G1:H26,ISERROR(XMATCH(G1:G26&H1:H26,J1:J30&K1:K30)))` if your USD values are in the columns H and K